# water for brewing

Tags: water, extract-brewing

I used tap water for my first batch and it came out with a little off taste and flavor that I referred to as a bandaid. I looked it up and found it could be the water I am using, are there any good suggestions as to what water is best for brewing? The quickest and easiest solutions will be the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bandaid flavors in beer can come from a couple of sources. I wouldn't blame the water first, my guess it's [Brettanomyces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brettanomyces) which is a spoilage yeast. It can give a variety of flavors but one of the bad ones is bandaid flavors. It's a common problem in beer and wine where sanitation has not been the best. This is my first guess. Another source could be your water. [Some people suggest](https://beerandbrewing.com/off-flavor-phenolic/) that the chlorine in your water can produce a bandaid like flavor. The yeast reacts with phenols produced by the yeast and produces a chemical reminiscent of bandaids. To avoid this, either buy bottled water at your grocery store (those filling stations are cheap) or use campden tablets to neutralize the chlorine.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Looking forward to testing it out.

Comment: Also, go to your local grocery store and buy reverse osmosis water. Most Walmarts, Safeways, etc have one of them and it's about $0.40 a gallon. Well worth it.

Comment: Is that ready to use without adding anything to it?

Comment: You will have to add back some minerals depending on what you recipe calls for.

Comment: Our water treatment agency, in Europe, recommends introducing ascorbic acid to neutralize chlorine. This maybe depends on the type oxidizer used in water treatment. I use a tip of a knife’s amount, barely a comprehensible amount for my 1.3 us gallon batches. Definitely not possible weigh imho.